# Why is CHECKDB reading the transaction log file on a database with a memory optimized table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, transaction-log, dbcc-checkdb

**tl;dr**: why is CHECKDB reading the transaction log for a user database with memory optimized tables?

---

It appears that CHECKDB is reading the transaction log file of the user database when it's checking on one of my databases - in particular, a database that uses in-memory OLTP tables.

CHECKDB for this database still finishes in a reasonable amount of time, so I'm mostly just curious about the behavior; but it's definitely the longest duration for CHECKDB of all the databases on this instance.

In looking over Paul Randal's epic "[CHECKDB From Every Angle: Complete description of all CHECKDB stages,](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/checkdb-from-every-angle-complete-description-of-all-checkdb-stages/)" I see that pre-SQL 2005 CHECKDB *used to* read the log in order to get a consistent view of the database.  But since this is 2016, it uses [an internal database snapshot.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql#internal-database-snapshot)

However, one of the [prerequisites for snapshots](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/database-snapshots-sql-server#Prerequisites) is that:

> The source database must not contain a MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA filegroup

My user database has one of these filegroups, so it looks like snapshots are off the table.

According to [the CHECKDB docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkdb-transact-sql#internal-database-snapshot):

> If a snapshot cannot be created, or TABLOCK is specified, DBCC CHECKDB acquires locks to obtain the required consistency. In this case, an exclusive database lock is required to perform the allocation checks, and shared table locks are required to perform the table checks.

Okay, so we're doing database and table locking instead of snapshots.  But that still doesn't explain why it has to read the transaction log.  So what gives?

I've provided a script below to reproduce the scenario.  It uses `sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats` to identify the log file reads.

Note that most of the time it reads a small portion of the log (480 KB), but it occasionally reads much more (48.2 MB).  In my production scenario, it reads most of the log file (~1.3 GB of the 2 GB file) every night at midnight when we run CHECKDB.

Here's an example of the outputs I've gotten so far with the script:

```
collection_time            num_of_reads     num_of_bytes_read
2018-04-04 15:12:29.203    106              50545664
```

Or this:

```
collection_time            num_of_reads     num_of_bytes_read
2018-04-04 15:25:14.227    1                491520
```

If I replace the memory optimized objects with regular tables, the output looks like this:

```
collection_time            num_of_reads     num_of_bytes_read
2018-04-04 15:21:03.207    0                0
```

**Why is CHECKDB reading the log file?  And especially, why does it occasionally read a much larger portion of the log file?**

Here is the actual script:

```
-- let's have a fresh DB
USE [master];

IF (DB_ID(N'LogFileRead_Test') IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test];
END

GO
CREATE DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]

GO
ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
MODIFY FILE
(
    NAME = LogFileRead_Test_log,
    SIZE = 128MB
);

-- Hekaton-yeah, I want memory optimized data
GO
ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
ADD FILEGROUP [LatencyTestInMemoryFileGroup] CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA;

GO
ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
ADD FILE 
(
    NAME = [LatencyTestInMemoryFile], 
    FILENAME = 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.SQL2016\MSSQL\DATA\LogFileRead_Test_SessionStateInMemoryFile'
) TO FILEGROUP [LatencyTestInMemoryFileGroup];

GO
USE [LogFileRead_Test]

GO
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[InMemoryIdTable] AS TABLE (
    [InMemoryId] NVARCHAR (88) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH ([InMemoryId]) WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 240))
    WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON);

GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InMemoryStuff] (
    [InMemoryId]   NVARCHAR (88)    COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [Created]     DATETIME2 (7)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_InMemoryStuff_InMemoryId] PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED HASH ([InMemoryId]) WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 240)
)
WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON);

GO
-- RBAR is the new black (we need some logs to read)
declare @j int = 0;
while @j < 100000
begin
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[InMemoryStuff](InMemoryId, Created) VALUES ('Description' + CAST(@j as varchar), GETDATE());
    set @j = @j + 1;
end

-- grab a baseline of virtual file stats to be diff'd later
select f.num_of_reads, f.num_of_bytes_read
into #dm_io_virtual_file_stats
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(default, default) f
where database_id = db_id('LogFileRead_Test') and file_id = FILE_IDEX('LogFileRead_Test_log');

-- hands off my log file, CHECKDB!
GO
DBCC CHECKDB ([LogFileRead_Test]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY;

-- grab the latest virtual file stats, and compare with the previous capture
GO
select f.num_of_reads, f.num_of_bytes_read
into #checkdb_stats
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(default, default) f
where database_id = db_id('LogFileRead_Test') and file_id = FILE_IDEX('LogFileRead_Test_log');

select 
        collection_time = GETDATE() 
        , num_of_reads = - f.num_of_reads + t.num_of_reads
        , num_of_bytes_read = - f.num_of_bytes_read + t.num_of_bytes_read
into #dm_io_virtual_file_stats_diff
from #dm_io_virtual_file_stats f, #checkdb_stats t;

drop table #checkdb_stats;
drop table #dm_io_virtual_file_stats;

-- CHECKDB ignored my comment
select collection_time, num_of_reads, num_of_bytes_read
from #dm_io_virtual_file_stats_diff d
order by d.collection_time;

drop table #dm_io_virtual_file_stats_diff;

-- I was *not* raised in a barn
USE [master];

ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test];
```

Since this repro generally just generates 1 or 106 log file reads, I thought I'd dig into the 1 with a file_read and file_read_completed extended events session.

```
name                timestamp                   mode        offset  database_id file_id size    duration
file_read           2018-04-06 10:51:11.1098141 Contiguous  72704   9           2       0       NULL    
file_read_completed 2018-04-06 10:51:11.1113345 Contiguous  72704   9           2       491520  1
```

And here's the VLF details (`DBCC LOGINFO()`) for context on those offsets and such:

```
RecoveryUnitId  FileId  FileSize    StartOffset FSeqNo  Status  Parity  CreateLSN
0               2       2031616     8192        34      2       64      0
0               2       2031616     2039808     35      2       64      0
0               2       2031616     4071424     36      2       64      0
0               2       2285568     6103040     37      2       64      0
0               2       15728640    8388608     38      2       64      34000000005200001
0               2       15728640    24117248    39      2       64      34000000005200001
0               2       15728640    39845888    40      2       64      34000000005200001
0               2       15728640    55574528    0       0       0       34000000005200001
0               2       15728640    71303168    0       0       0       34000000005200001
0               2       15728640    87031808    0       0       0       34000000005200001
0               2       15728640    102760448   0       0       0       34000000005200001
0               2       15728640    118489088   0       0       0       34000000005200001
```

So, the CHECKDB operation:

- started reading 63 KB (64,512 bytes) into the first VLF,
- read 480 KB (491,520 bytes), and
- did *not* read the last 1441 KB (1,475,584 bytes) of the VLF

I also captured the callstacks, in case they are helpful.

file_read callstack:

```
(00007ffd`999a0860)   sqlmin!XeSqlPkg::file_read::Publish+0x1dc   |  (00007ffd`999a0b40)   sqlmin!XeSqlPkg::file_read_enqueued::Publish
(00007ffd`9a825e30)   sqlmin!FireReadEvent+0x118   |  (00007ffd`9a825f60)   sqlmin!FireReadEnqueuedEvent
(00007ffd`9980b500)   sqlmin!FCB::AsyncRead+0x74d   |  (00007ffd`9980b800)   sqlmin!FCB::AsyncReadInternal
(00007ffd`9970e9d0)   sqlmin!SQLServerLogMgr::LogBlockReadAheadAsync+0x6a6   |  (00007ffd`9970ec00)   sqlmin!LBH::Destuff
(00007ffd`9970a6d0)   sqlmin!LogConsumer::GetNextLogBlock+0x1591   |  (00007ffd`9970ab70)   sqlmin!LogPoolPrivateCacheBufferMgr::Lookup
(00007ffd`9a9fcbd0)   sqlmin!SQLServerLogIterForward::GetNext+0x258   |  (00007ffd`9a9fd2d0)   sqlmin!SQLServerLogIterForward::GetNextBlock
(00007ffd`9aa417f0)   sqlmin!SQLServerCOWLogIterForward::GetNext+0x2b   |  (00007ffd`9aa418c0)   sqlmin!SQLServerCOWLogIterForward::StartScan
(00007ffd`9aa64210)   sqlmin!RecoveryMgr::AnalysisPass+0x83b   |  (00007ffd`9aa65100)   sqlmin!RecoveryMgr::AnalyzeLogRecord
(00007ffd`9aa5ed50)   sqlmin!RecoveryMgr::PhysicalRedo+0x233   |  (00007ffd`9aa5f790)   sqlmin!RecoveryMgr::PhysicalCompletion
(00007ffd`9aa7fd90)   sqlmin!RecoveryUnit::PhysicalRecovery+0x358   |  (00007ffd`9aa802c0)   sqlmin!RecoveryUnit::CompletePhysical
(00007ffd`9a538b90)   sqlmin!StartupCoordinator::NotifyPhaseStart+0x3a   |  (00007ffd`9a538bf0)   sqlmin!StartupCoordinator::NotifyPhaseEnd
(00007ffd`9a80c430)   sqlmin!DBTABLE::ReplicaCreateStartup+0x2f4   |  (00007ffd`9a80c820)   sqlmin!DBTABLE::RefreshPostRecovery
(00007ffd`9a7ed0b0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::SyncAndLinkReplicaRecoveryPhase+0x890   |  (00007ffd`9a7edff0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::DetachDB
(00007ffd`9a7f2cd0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::CreatePhasedTransientReplica+0x869   |  (00007ffd`9a7f3630)   sqlmin!DBMgr::StrandTransientReplica
(00007ffd`9a7f2ae0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::CreateTransientReplica+0x118   |  (00007ffd`9a7f2cd0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::CreatePhasedTransientReplica
(00007ffd`99ec6d30)   sqlmin!DBDDLAgent::CreateReplica+0x1b5   |  (00007ffd`99ec6f90)   sqlmin!FSystemDatabase
(00007ffd`9abaaeb0)   sqlmin!UtilDbccCreateReplica+0x82   |  (00007ffd`9abab000)   sqlmin!UtilDbccDestroyReplica
(00007ffd`9ab0d7e0)   sqlmin!UtilDbccCheckDatabase+0x994   |  (00007ffd`9ab0ffd0)   sqlmin!UtilDbccRetainReplica
(00007ffd`9ab0cfc0)   sqlmin!DbccCheckDB+0x22d   |  (00007ffd`9ab0d380)   sqlmin!DbccCheckFilegroup
(00007ffd`777379c0)   sqllang!DbccCommand::Execute+0x193   |  (00007ffd`77737d70)   sqllang!DbccHelp
(00007ffd`777e58d0)   sqllang!CStmtDbcc::XretExecute+0x889   |  (00007ffd`777e6250)   sqllang!UtilDbccSetPermissionFailure
(00007ffd`76b02eb0)   sqllang!CMsqlExecContext::ExecuteStmts<1,1>+0x40d   |  (00007ffd`76b03410)   sqllang!CSQLSource::CleanupCompileXactState
(00007ffd`76b03a60)   sqllang!CMsqlExecContext::FExecute+0xa9e   |  (00007ffd`76b043d0)   sqllang!CCacheObject::Release
(00007ffd`76b03430)   sqllang!CSQLSource::Execute+0x981   |  (00007ffd`76b039b0)   sqllang!CSQLLock::Cleanup
```

file_read_completed callstack:

```
(00007ffd`99995cc0)   sqlmin!XeSqlPkg::file_read_completed::Publish+0x1fc   |  (00007ffd`99995fe0)   sqlmin!XeSqlPkg::file_write_completed::Publish
(00007ffd`9a826630)   sqlmin!FireIoCompletionEventLong+0x227   |  (00007ffd`9a8269c0)   sqlmin!IoRequestDispenser::Dump
(00007ffd`9969bee0)   sqlmin!FCB::IoCompletion+0x8e   |  (00007ffd`9969c180)   sqlmin!IoRequestDispenser::Put
(00007ffd`beaa11e0)   sqldk!IOQueue::CheckForIOCompletion+0x426   |  (00007ffd`beaa1240)   sqldk!SystemThread::GetCurrentId
(00007ffd`beaa15b0)   sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::SwitchContext+0x173   |  (00007ffd`beaa18a0)   sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::Switch
(00007ffd`beaa1d00)   sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::SuspendNonPreemptive+0xd3   |  (00007ffd`beaa1db0)   sqldk!SOS_Scheduler::ResumeNoCuzz
(00007ffd`99641720)   sqlmin!EventInternal<SuspendQueueSLock>::Wait+0x1e7   |  (00007ffd`99641ae0)   sqlmin!SOS_DispatcherPool<DispatcherWorkItem,DispatcherWorkItem,SOS_DispatcherQueue<DispatcherWorkItem,0,DispatcherWorkItem>,DispatcherPoolConfig,void * __ptr64>::GetDispatchers
(00007ffd`9aa437c0)   sqlmin!SQLServerLogMgr::CheckLogBlockReadComplete+0x1e6   |  (00007ffd`9aa44670)   sqlmin!SQLServerLogMgr::ValidateBlock
(00007ffd`9970a6d0)   sqlmin!LogConsumer::GetNextLogBlock+0x1b37   |  (00007ffd`9970ab70)   sqlmin!LogPoolPrivateCacheBufferMgr::Lookup
(00007ffd`9a9fcbd0)   sqlmin!SQLServerLogIterForward::GetNext+0x258   |  (00007ffd`9a9fd2d0)   sqlmin!SQLServerLogIterForward::GetNextBlock
(00007ffd`9aa417f0)   sqlmin!SQLServerCOWLogIterForward::GetNext+0x2b   |  (00007ffd`9aa418c0)   sqlmin!SQLServerCOWLogIterForward::StartScan
(00007ffd`9aa64210)   sqlmin!RecoveryMgr::AnalysisPass+0x83b   |  (00007ffd`9aa65100)   sqlmin!RecoveryMgr::AnalyzeLogRecord
(00007ffd`9aa5ed50)   sqlmin!RecoveryMgr::PhysicalRedo+0x233   |  (00007ffd`9aa5f790)   sqlmin!RecoveryMgr::PhysicalCompletion
(00007ffd`9aa7fd90)   sqlmin!RecoveryUnit::PhysicalRecovery+0x358   |  (00007ffd`9aa802c0)   sqlmin!RecoveryUnit::CompletePhysical
(00007ffd`9a538b90)   sqlmin!StartupCoordinator::NotifyPhaseStart+0x3a   |  (00007ffd`9a538bf0)   sqlmin!StartupCoordinator::NotifyPhaseEnd
(00007ffd`9a80c430)   sqlmin!DBTABLE::ReplicaCreateStartup+0x2f4   |  (00007ffd`9a80c820)   sqlmin!DBTABLE::RefreshPostRecovery
(00007ffd`9a7ed0b0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::SyncAndLinkReplicaRecoveryPhase+0x890   |  (00007ffd`9a7edff0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::DetachDB
(00007ffd`9a7f2cd0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::CreatePhasedTransientReplica+0x869   |  (00007ffd`9a7f3630)   sqlmin!DBMgr::StrandTransientReplica
(00007ffd`9a7f2ae0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::CreateTransientReplica+0x118   |  (00007ffd`9a7f2cd0)   sqlmin!DBMgr::CreatePhasedTransientReplica
(00007ffd`99ec6d30)   sqlmin!DBDDLAgent::CreateReplica+0x1b5   |  (00007ffd`99ec6f90)   sqlmin!FSystemDatabase
(00007ffd`9abaaeb0)   sqlmin!UtilDbccCreateReplica+0x82   |  (00007ffd`9abab000)   sqlmin!UtilDbccDestroyReplica
(00007ffd`9ab0d7e0)   sqlmin!UtilDbccCheckDatabase+0x994   |  (00007ffd`9ab0ffd0)   sqlmin!UtilDbccRetainReplica
(00007ffd`9ab0cfc0)   sqlmin!DbccCheckDB+0x22d   |  (00007ffd`9ab0d380)   sqlmin!DbccCheckFilegroup
(00007ffd`777379c0)   sqllang!DbccCommand::Execute+0x193   |  (00007ffd`77737d70)   sqllang!DbccHelp
```

These stacktraces correlate with [Hannah's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/203275/) indicating that CHECKDB is using an internal snapshot in spite of the presence of the Hekaton tables.

I've read that snapshots perform recovery to [undo uncommitted transactions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187054(v=sql.105).aspx):

> Uncommitted transactions are rolled back in a newly created database snapshot because the Database Engine runs recovery after the snapshot has been created (transactions in the database are not affected).

But this still doesn't explain why a large chunk of the log file is often read in my production scenario (and occasionally in the repro provided here).  I don't think I have that many in-flight transactions at a given time in my app, and there certainly aren't any in the repro here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Even though the SQL Server documentation states that databases with "In-Memory" tables do not support snapshots, the "internal" snapshot required for `DBCC CHECKDB` can still be created since the checkdb operation does not touch in-memory tables, and the snapshot only captures changes to the on-disk tables.

Presumably, Microsoft chose to prevent user-created snapshots on databases with In-Memory tables since they would need to duplicate the in-memory structures in order for the snapshot to really be a complete snapshot from the normal, user-centric, sense.  Duplicating the in-memory tables for a snapshot could easily make the server run out of memory, which is *not* A Good Thing™

You can prove for yourself that an internal DBCC snapshot is being created by watching the data folder where the primary database datafile resides while running `DBCC CHECKDB`.  If an internal snapshot is created, you'll see a file named `LogFileRead_Test.mdf_MSSQL_DBCC7` (the `7` may be different - it represents the database id for your database).

Once the snapshot file has been created, it is necessary for SQL Server to run recovery on the database to bring it into a consistent state that is required for DBCC CHECKDB to run.  Any log-reading action you're seeing is likely to be a result of that recovery process.  I built a quick rig for checking the output of multiple `DBCC CHECKDB` actions, which proves that if there are no transactions between checkdbs, there are no log-file reads.

```
USE master;
SET IMPLICIT_TRANSACTIONS OFF;
USE [master];
IF (DB_ID(N'LogFileRead_Test') IS NOT NULL) 
BEGIN
    ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
    SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
    DROP DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test];
END

CREATE DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
MODIFY FILE
(
    NAME = LogFileRead_Test_log,
    SIZE = 128MB
);

ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
ADD FILEGROUP [LatencyTestInMemoryFileGroup] CONTAINS MEMORY_OPTIMIZED_DATA;
ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
ADD FILE 
(
    NAME = [LatencyTestInMemoryFile], 
    FILENAME = 'C:\temp\LogFileRead_Test_SessionStateInMemoryFile'
) TO FILEGROUP [LatencyTestInMemoryFileGroup];
GO

USE LogFileRead_Test;

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InMemoryStuff] (
    [InMemoryId]   NVARCHAR (88)    COLLATE Latin1_General_100_BIN2 NOT NULL,
    [Created]     DATETIME2 (7)    NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_InMemoryStuff_InMemoryId] 
    PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED 
    HASH ([InMemoryId]) WITH (BUCKET_COUNT = 240)
)
WITH (MEMORY_OPTIMIZED = ON);

;WITH src AS (
    SELECT n.Num
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))n(Num)
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[InMemoryStuff] (InMemoryId, Created) 
SELECT 'Description' + CONVERT(varchar(30)
        , ((s1.Num * 10000) 
         + (s2.Num * 1000) 
         + (s3.Num * 100) 
         + (s4.Num * 10) 
         + (s5.Num)))
    , GETDATE()
FROM src s1
    CROSS JOIN src s2
    CROSS JOIN src s3
    CROSS JOIN src s4
    CROSS JOIN src s5;
USE master;

DECLARE @cmd nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @msg nvarchar(1000);
DECLARE @l int;
DECLARE @m int;
SET @m = 10;
SET @l = 1;
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#vfs', N'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #vfs;
CREATE TABLE #vfs (
    vfs_run int NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    , collection_time datetime2(7)
    , num_of_reads bigint
    , num_of_bytes_read bigint
);

WHILE @l <= @m 
BEGIN
SET @msg = N'loop ' + CONVERT(nvarchar(10), @l);
RAISERROR (@msg, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT;

SET @cmd = 'USE [LogFileRead_Test];
-- grab a baseline of virtual file stats to be diff''d later
select f.num_of_reads, f.num_of_bytes_read
into #dm_io_virtual_file_stats
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(default, default) f
where database_id = db_id(''LogFileRead_Test'') and file_id = FILE_IDEX(''LogFileRead_Test_log'');

DBCC CHECKDB ([LogFileRead_Test]) WITH NO_INFOMSGS, ALL_ERRORMSGS, DATA_PURITY;

-- grab the latest virtual file stats, and compare with the previous capture
select f.num_of_reads, f.num_of_bytes_read
into #checkdb_stats
from sys.dm_io_virtual_file_stats(default, default) f
where database_id = db_id(''LogFileRead_Test'') and file_id = FILE_IDEX(''LogFileRead_Test_log'');

select 
        collection_time = GETDATE() 
        , num_of_reads = - f.num_of_reads + t.num_of_reads
        , num_of_bytes_read = - f.num_of_bytes_read + t.num_of_bytes_read
into #dm_io_virtual_file_stats_diff
from #dm_io_virtual_file_stats f, #checkdb_stats t;

--drop table #checkdb_stats;
--drop table #dm_io_virtual_file_stats;

-- CHECKDB ignored my comment
select collection_time, num_of_reads, num_of_bytes_read
from #dm_io_virtual_file_stats_diff d
order by d.collection_time;

--drop table #dm_io_virtual_file_stats_diff;
';
INSERT INTO #vfs (collection_time, num_of_reads, num_of_bytes_read)
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;

SET @l += 1;
END

USE master;
SET @cmd = 'USE [master];
ALTER DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test]
SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;
DROP DATABASE [LogFileRead_Test];
';
EXEC sys.sp_executesql @cmd;

SELECT *
FROM #vfs
ORDER BY vfs_run;
```

The results:

```
╔═════════╦═════════════════════════════╦══════════════╦═══════════════════╗
║ vfs_run ║       collection_time       ║ num_of_reads ║ num_of_bytes_read ║
╠═════════╬═════════════════════════════╬══════════════╬═══════════════════╣
║       1 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:37.6566667 ║            1 ║            491520 ║
║       2 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:37.8300000 ║            0 ║                 0 ║
║       3 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:38.0166667 ║            0 ║                 0 ║
║       4 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:38.1866667 ║            0 ║                 0 ║
║       5 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:38.3766667 ║            0 ║                 0 ║
║       6 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:38.5633333 ║            0 ║                 0 ║
║       7 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:38.7333333 ║            0 ║                 0 ║
║       8 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:38.9066667 ║            0 ║                 0 ║
║       9 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:39.0933333 ║            0 ║                 0 ║
║      10 ║ 2018-04-06 15:53:39.2800000 ║            0 ║                 0 ║
╚═════════╩═════════════════════════════╩══════════════╩═══════════════════╝
```

Also, instead of using an RBAR approach for inserting data into the test table, you may want to use a simple set-based approach, such as the one below:

```
;WITH src AS (
    SELECT n.Num
    FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))n(Num)
)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[InMemoryStuff] (InMemoryId, Created) 
SELECT 'Description' + CONVERT(varchar(30)
     , ((s1.Num * 10000) 
      + (s2.Num * 1000) 
      + (s3.Num * 100) 
      + (s4.Num * 10) 
      + (s5.Num)))
    , GETDATE()
FROM src s1
    CROSS JOIN src s2
    CROSS JOIN src s3
    CROSS JOIN src s4
    CROSS JOIN src s5;
```

In my test, it fills the table in under 3 seconds, whereas the RBAR approach takes *a long time*.  Also, nice comments in your code, made me lol.